# Conditional Select statemtn

Tags: sql

Using the AdventureWorks database, I need to produce a list of job titles and the amount of employees who are assigned to each of them. But that's not my concern.

When the OrganizationLevel is 2 or below, I need to make the Job Title field capitalized. However, I also need a condition that restricts job titles from being displayed when they're 3 or below. Can you please help me? Here is an (incorrect) attempt - I'm aware this is wrong, I've practically given up, but I'm hopeful it will help explain what I'm trying to achieve here.

```
SELECT distinct JobTitle, count(JobTitle) as CountOf from HumanResources.Employee 
WHERE (OrganizationLevel < 3) 
GROUP BY JobTitle 
ELSE IF (OrganizationLevel < 2) select distinct UPPER(JobTitle);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN OrganizationLevel < 2 THEN JobTitle 
    ELSE UPPER(JobTitle) 
  END as JobTitle, 
  count(*) as CountOf 
FROM HumanResources.Employee 
WHERE OrganizationLevel < 3
GROUP BY 
  CASE 
    WHEN OrganizationLevel < 2 THEN JobTitle 
    ELSE UPPER(JobTitle) 
  END
```

Comment: Thank you. So, how would I now alter your SQL so that, if OrganizationLevel = 1, JobTitle = "MANAGING DIRECTOR" ?

Comment: SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN OrganizationLevel = 1 THEN 'MANAGING DIRECTOR'
    WHEN OrganizationLevel < 2 THEN JobTitle 
    ELSE UPPER(JobTitle) 
  END as JobTitle